# How use multi interface class in Spring4D

Tags: delphi, interface, spring4d

I'm just learning Spring4D and i have one question.
If class implement only one interface its all clear:

```
    IWeapon = interface
        ['{E679EDA6-5D43-44AD-8F96-3B5BD43A147B}']
        procedure Attack;
    end;

    TSword = class(TInterfacedObject, IWeapon)
    public
        procedure Attack;
    end;

    GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TSword>.Implements<IWeapon>('sword');
    sword := ServiceLocator.GetService<IWeapon>('sword');
```

and im really happy now, I have sword and i dont need to Free it.

but if class implements two or more interfaces:

```
    IWeapon = interface
        ['{E679EDA6-5D43-44AD-8F96-3B5BD43A147B}']
        procedure Attack;
    end;

    IShield = interface
        ['{B2B2F443-85FE-489C-BAF4-538BB5B377B3}']
        function Block: Integer;
    end;

    TSpikedShield = class(TInterfacedObject, IWeapon, IShield)
    public
        function Block: Integer;
        procedure Attack;
    end;

    GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TSpikedShield>.Implements<IWeapon>.Implements<IShield>;
```

I can ask ServiceLocator for an instance of TSpikedShield but i need choose one IWeapon or IShield. But I want use it in two ways(or i shouldn't want?) like:

```
spikedShield.Attack;
spikedShield.Block;
```

So if I good undestand, I have to create instance of TSpikedShiled directly(i mean without interface).

```
function MakeSpikedShield: TSpickedShield;
begin
    result := TSpickedShield.Create;
end;
```

There is any way to use this class but with automagical Free?

(there won't be problem if interfaces could implement multi interfeces but its not allowed in delphi)

Edited:
maybe somethink like that?

```
ISpikedSield = interface
    function AsWeapon: IWeapon;
    function AsShield: IShield;
end;
TSpikedShield = class(TInterfacedObject, ISpikedShield)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There won't be problem if interfaces could implement multi interfaces but it's not allowed in Delphi

That is the exact cause of the problem.

I would just make an `ISpikedShield` interface that has the methods of `IWeapon` and `IShield` and making sure that every class that implements `ISpikedShield` also explicitly implements `IWeapon` and `IShield` (this is what the compiler basically does for you in C# for example where an interface can inherit from multiple other interfaces).

You then cannot assign an `ISpikedShield` to an `IWeapon` and `IShield` but using as operator will work because the class behind implements them.

However I am not sure if there is not a misconception in your architecture because if you think further there won't be a class that has an `ISpikedShield` as dependency but rather an `IWeapon` and/or `IShield`. Some game code would then check if your `IShield` supports `ICanAttack` to do an additional hit apart from those you can do with your `IWeapon`.